# Added data to postgres in rails 4.0 console not visible in pgAdmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pgadmin

I am following this rather good [rails tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#fnref-6_4) as an introduction to the world of ruby on rails.

I have configured my sample app to use postgresql in line with the Heroku site where it is distributed. I can create tables in the database by generating the migration file using `rails generate model user name:string email:string` and then running `bundle rake bd:migrate`.

After doing this I can see the tables using pgAdmin3. I then run the rails console in sandbox mode and create some user objects using the active record methods.

```
user = User.new(name: "Russell Ormes", email: "russell@ormes.com")
=> #<User id: nil, name: "Russell Ormes", email: "russell@ormes.com", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):003:0> user.save
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (93.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 29 Nov 2013 15:08:30 UTC +00:00], ["email", "russell@ormes.com"], ["name", "Russell Ormes"], ["updated_at", Fri, 29 Nov 2013 15:08:30 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> true
```

and a second user

```
irb(main):005:0> User.create(name: "A Nother", email: "another@example.org")
   (0.3ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", Fri, 29 Nov 2013 15:15:23 UTC +00:00], ["email", "another@example.org"], ["name", "A Nother"], ["updated_at", Fri, 29 Nov 2013 15:15:23 UTC +00:00]]
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> #<User id: 2, name: "A Nother", email: "another@example.org", created_at: "2013-11-29 15:15:23", updated_at: "2013-11-29 15:15:23">
```

Now I can access these users from the rails console using the `User.all`

```
irb(main):010:0> User.all
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "Russell Ormes", email: "russell@ormes.com", created_at: "2013-11-29 15:08:30", updated_at: "2013-11-29 15:08:30">, #<User id: 2, name: "A Nother", email: "another@example.org", created_at: "2013-11-29 15:15:23", updated_at: "2013-11-29 15:15:23">]>
```

However, when I access the database through pgAdmin3 it shows me no data. (As a new member I don't have enough reputation points to post an image).

I am logging in to pgAdmin3 using the same username as rails (sample) and so feel I should have permission to view any data. Any ideas why I can't see anything? IS this to do with running the console in sandbox mode? I thought it would add the data to the database and them rollback the database on logout.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're running in sanbox mode, you're effectively running a [database transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction), which by definition is atomic and isolated. This means that you cannot view the results of the transaction until a COMMIT or ROLLBACK have occured.

This is why you can't see the results in pgAdmin in the same time while you're in the sandbox.

Comment: Thanks mihai, so it is the sandbox mode that is the issue. 

Do you know anyway to view the transaction using pgAdmin? 

Thanks

Comment: You can't view it from the outside due to the same reason (isolation)...that's how transactions work. I'm not sure if Heroku enforces you to use the sandbox, but if you're just learning Rails I think you're better off if you install Postgres locally, far more convenient.

Comment: Yep, I agree. This is all running on my laptop. I am looking into transaction now but in the context of php and mySQL, but I suppose the theory will easily translate to ruby and Postgres.